# React native iOS build failing on M1 giving error with Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1ed9bfbc8) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x10cc90318). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

I am trying to run react native app on MacBook Pro { m1 chip }. Xcode version 13.2.1. Have tried many solutions so please do not mark as duplicate as none of the solution is working for me.

some of tried solutions are -
solutions with pod installation and excluding arm64 architecture in build setting.
Please help!

Comment: you said you tried with pod installation - have you tried `cd ios && rm -rf Pods && pod install`?  Sometimes I get a similar error until I delete the pods folder and reinstall.  Also try cleaning the build folder in Xcode

Comment: yes I tried it..but nothing worked @Abe

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help since I had something similar and I found this question!

I was installing TheCodingMachine React Native boilerplate 3.2.5 [link](https://github.com/thecodingmachine/react-native-boilerplate) and I got a similar error.

**Decision.** Updated the React Native version

```
//react-native": "0.66.4" ->  "react-native": "0.67.3"

cd ios && rm -rf Pods && pod install
```

And an `nvm` update can also help.